# Search using space character between name and extension

Tags: windows-search

I have many duplicate files with one of them having a space added to the end of the name, such as "FileName.dll" and "FileName .dll". Can Windows 8.1 Search for just those files with the space added? If so, how?

Joe

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. Use quotes. I tried it on file `test .txt`, searched using "test .txt" in Windows Explorer, and it worked.

Comment: OP is looking for more robust solution so that search doesn't show two files. Original and other with extra space